# How to access task variables between the tasks in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have a simple playbook like bellow which consists of a few tasks. On top of a playbook, I am creating the YAML file from provided CSV file, but if I want to define a variable within the task, this variable is not defined in another task. So what is visibility or/and scope of Ansible variables? I know if I define the variable within the hosts section that variable will persists in all tasks, but as I will define variable dynamically this is not a good approach.

```
- name: Create IAM users
  vars:
    password: Sometestpassword123
  iam:
    iam_type: user
    name: "{{ item.username }}"
    password: "{{ password }}"
    access_key_state: create
    state: present
    groups: "{{ item.group }}"

  with_items:
    - "{{ users.users }}"
  register: user

- name: Create a file with user credentials
  local_action: template src=template.j2 dest=./users_credentials.csv
```

So, if I am defining the password within the task, this variable is used as a module parameter, but I can't reuse this variable in the second task, where I want to concatenate the first task filtered output in a registered variable with the defined variable, which will be dynamically changed in each iteration of loop.

```
 TASK [Create a file with user credentials] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
    fatal: [localhost -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'password' is undefined"}
```

Basically, I want to create the CSV file consisting of filtered iam module return values saved in registered variable 'user' and dynamically calculated value of 'password' variable.

Unfortunately, the AWS iam module doesn't return the password.

The template is really simple, as for testing purpose I just want a value of the 'password' value defined in a task. Here it goes.

```
{{ password }}
```

Comment: @techraf Exactly. I shoul edit the question.

Comment: Now the answer is "you cannot".

Comment: why doing that way and not with `set_fact`?

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing the answer provided by @imjoseangel.
you can define the variable using **set_fact** which can be accessible to the **subsequent plays**.

Sample snippet :

```
---
- name : Test set_fact Variable
  hosts : localhost
  tasks:
    - name : Set Password Variable
      set_fact:
        password : 'Abcd123'
    - name : Copy Template
      template :
        src : template.j2
        dest : ./template.csv
```

-

```
---
- name : Test set_fact Variable
  hosts : localhost
  tasks:
  - name : Set Password Variable
    set_fact:
      password : 'Abcd123'

- name :  Apply set_fact Variable
  hosts : localhost
  tasks:
  - name : Copy Template
    template :
      src : template.j2
      dest : ./template.csv
```